# How do class methods return in php

Tags: php

I'm not particularly familiar with php, and I'm having trouble understanding what's happening. Using a condensed skeleton of what I have:

```
class Helper
{
    public function __construct($value)
    {
         $this->value = $value;
         //etc
    }

    private function prefix($val)
    {
         return '1234' . $val;
    }

    private function otherFunction()
    {
        $this->value->someFunction(function ($err, $result) {
            if($err !== null) {
                echo $err->getMessage();
            }
            return $result;
        });
    }

    public function help()
    {
        echo $this->prefix('5678'); //outputs 12345678
        echo is_null($this->otherFunction()); //outputs 1
    }
}
```

Why does otherFunction return null? I can `echo $result` right before the `return` and see what I'm expecting, but it's null afterwards.

Comment: it doesn't appear that `otherFunction` returns anything - you're just calling `$this->value->someFunction` (whatever that is), and passing in an anonymous function to it. *That* (anonymous) function is what returns `$result`, but the `otherFunction` method itself does nothing other than make this function call, and in particular doesn't return anything.[It also appears you're missing a closing `)` here - so it's possible I've misread your intention.]

Comment: That does make things clearer, thank you. How can I get the return of the anonymous function to be returned by `otherFunction` ?

Comment: As @vich says in his answer, you can just add `return` before the function call: `return $this->value->someFunction(...)`.

Comment: We don't see it here, but be also be sure that `someFunction` returns the value that the callback returns to it. Each nested function needs to return its value to the function that called it.

Comment: `__construct(someclass $value)` would be better.  If you are going to assume that it has a callable method of `someFunction`.  If I put `new Helper(0)` this would blow up when you call that in `Helper::otherFunction()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `otherFunction()` doesn't return anything. Probably you `echo $result` inside of the callback function passed to `$this->value->someFunction()`.

Add `return` just before `$this->value->someFunction(...` to return the value from `otherFunction()`.

Comment: Just to clearfiy the return is inside of the scope of a closure (anonymous function) not the scope of the class method.  Therefore, it is correct to say the method does not return anything.

Comment: Thank you, that helped clear things up. Simply adding `return` as suggested did not suffice, though - I had to edit the callback function to `use (&$output)` and change `return $result` to `$output = $result`, then `return $output` before the closing brace of `otherFunction`

Comment: Your solution will work. But it's more like workaround. Could not you modify someFunction() to add return there?

Comment: In what I'm working with, someFunction() is from a library, so I'm hesitant to try to edit it.